# JQuery in WPF - Best practice

Tags: jquery, wpf, charts

I know that there are many cool, powerful and, primarly, free libraries for the web side. For example chart libraries like http://www.chartjs.org/

For WPF this is not alwasy true. So, my question:

Q: What do you think about the idea to use web components (obviously in a WebBrowser Control) in a WPF application when there are no attractive free alternatives?

Comment: I'm really, really curious about the "genius" who voted -1 ... :D
If you do not agree, please write here what do you think (if there is something that you think...)

Comment: I know what you mean, thats why I am buulding this, maybe it can help you too https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Comment: This is useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried porting a web component to WPF, though xaml has similarities to html, i'm not sure that it directly supports javascript.

Here's a potential replacement for charting if you're looking for one

- http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/
- http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ - has simple charts for free, or more advanced chart with a cost.

Comment: Thank you for this reply.
I do not mean "porting" but use JQuery in a WebBrowser Control

Comment: I'm guessing that's possible ... it's kinda like having a webview embedded within your WPF app ... that's like using HTML/JS to develop a phone app. In this case, really you're creating a offline web app - you really do not need WPF.